# Doubling time on R

Tags: r

I have a problem with calculating the doubling time for cancer growth in R. The data contains multiple scans of the same patient taken over 5 years. There seem to be, however, cases where the patient has been scanned multiple times in a year. I want to calculate the doubling time of the mass of nodes for all patients for 1 scan and the last scan.

I have calculated the doubling time of a node of the last patient, but I need to get the doubling time for all patients.

The code i have used:

```
Nod <- read.table("NoData270513.txt" , header = T) 


Nod$CoNo <- 10*Nod$StNo + Nod$LeNo

length(Nod$CoNo); length(unique (Nod$CoNo))

Nod$CoNo <- factor(Nod$CoNo)
Nod$CTDato <- as.Date(Nod$CTDato)

NodTyp1 <- rep(NA, length(unique(Nod$CoNo)))



i <- 0; i1 <- 0; i2 <- 0

for (j in unique(Nod$CoNo)) { temp <- Nod[Nod$CoNo==j, ]

i <- i + 1; i1 <- i2 + 1; i2 <- i2 + length(temp$CoNo)


NodTyp1[1:20]
vdt <- rep(NA, 1216)

if (length(temp$Age) > 1 )
{
    vdt[j] <- (as.numeric(temp$CTDato[length(temp$Age)]) - as.numeric(temp$CTDato[1])) * log(2)/log((temp$SDia[length(temp$Age)]/temp$SDia[1]))
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what the different columns of `Nod` are and also put some comments into your code to explain what you're trying to do? It would also be good to see the first few lines of example data from your input file. (It's useful to prefix code with 4 spaces for formatting reasons by the way.)

Answer (score 0):

If I got it right, the only thing you need is to create a function that takes data `filename` and returns what you need. Then just iterate through all data files.

It seems that will be the patern:

```
# declare function for one patient
calculate.doub.time <- function(filename){
   Nod <- read.table(filename , header = T) 
   # ...
   # ...
   # return what you want
}

# calculate all data files
all.data <- list.files() # assuming your working directory contains all data
result <- sapply(all.data, calculate.doub.time)
```

Sorry in advance if I misunderstood what you want to achieve.